# How to "Group/Collapse" multiple notifications in the notification center if come from same converstation on iOS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

On Android, when supplying the same id in two calls to NotificationManager.notify, only one notification will be shown in the notification drawer.

But how to do it on iOS

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Notifications on iOS are not designed to be grouped/collapsed or replaced by other notifications. Just check other messenger apps, the convention is to have a separate notification for each message, contrary to Android. Also a message doesn't get replaced by a new message in the same conversation. The functionality that Android provides here simply doesn't exist in iOS.

What you could do instead is, to send silent notifications ("push-to-sync") and handle the grouping/replacing on client side, since you have more control over local notifications (e.g. you can remove single local notifications, but not single remote notifications). But keep in mind, if the app was force quit, it won't be woken up to process the silent notification.

I think your best option is to stick to the convention and don't group/replace notifications.

Answer (score 1):

about iOS you have to understand many things about the push notification

first it is not part of your app, in iOS it is separate application called notification centre that your app add itself to it so when APNS send a notification it send it to the notification centre in your iPhone not to your app.

so what you need to do will be in the server side not in the mobile side

for example let's say it is a chat application 
the server side should check if the message is sent from the same user

the badge count should remain the same and not to notify APNS with new count

and also in the server side 
the server will check if the message from the same user to send only sound notification not text or if the server got many message at once from the same user send the text with got many message from same user

but all of that is just work around as something like this is not provided yet in iOS may be in iOS9 as it become more open and not like previous versions

good luck